# CONTRAST for CLASS variable with more than two levels in PROC GLM

Tags: sas, contrast, categorical-data

*Background*: When we test the significance of a categorical variable that has been coded as dummy variables, we need to simultaneously test all dummy variables are 0. For example, if *X* takes on values of 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, I would fit dummy variables for levels 1-4 (assuming I want 0 to be baseline), then want to simultaneously test B1=B2=B3=B4=0.

If this is the only variable in my data set, I can use the overall *F*-statistic to achieve this. However, if I have other covariates, the overall *F*-test doesn't work.

In Stata, for example, this is (very, very) simply carried out by the `testparm` command as:
`testparm i.x` (after fitting the desired regression model), where the `i.` prefix tells Stata *X* is a categorical data to be treated as dummy variables.

*Question/issue*: I'm wondering how I can do this in SAS with a `CONTRAST` (or `ESTIMATE`?) statement while fitting a regression model with `PROC GLM.` Since I have scoured the internet and haven't found what I'm looking for, I'm guessing I'm  missing something very obvious. However, all of the examples I've seen are NOT for categorical (`class`) variables, but rather two separate (say continuous) variables. The contrast statement in that case would simply be something like

`CONTRAST 'Contrast1' y 1 z 1;`

Otherwise, they're for calculating hypotheses like H_0: B1-B2=0.

I feel like I need to breakdown the hypotheses into smaller pieces and determine that set that defines the whole relationship, but I'm not doing it correctly. For example, for B1=B2=B3=B4=0, I thought I might say B1=B2=B3=-B4, then define (1) B1=-B4, (2) B2=-B4 and (3) B2=B3. I was trying to code this as a `CONTRAST` statement as (say *X* is in descending order in data set: 4-0):

```
CONTRAST 'Contrast' x -1 0 0 1 0
                    x -1 0 1 0 0
                    x 0 1 1 0 0;
```

I know this is not correct, and I tried many, many variations and whatever random logic I could come up with. My problem is I have relatively novice-level knowledge of `CONTRAST` (and unfortunately have not found great documentation to help with this) and also of how this hypothesis test should really be formulated for the sake of estimation (do I try to split it up into pieces as I did above, or...?).

Comment: Can you use an LR test?  I'm pretty sure you can use GLM to do a MLE and get the log likelihood from the fit with and without your dummy variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my note above, you actually can get SAS to do this for you with `PROC GENMOD` and the `CLASS` statement and a `TYPE3` specification.

```
proc genmod data=input;
class classvar ;
model slope= classvar othervar/  type3;
run;
quit;
```

In the example above, my class levels are in the `classvar` variable.  The `othervar` is my other covariate.

At the end of the output, you see a table labeled `LR Statistics For Type 3 Analysis`.  The row for `classvar` is the LR test of all the class effects=0.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I am open to "work arounds" in the sense of using other procedures. I'm just wondering, however, the more "general" way of using CONTRAST statements so that in theory I could complete the test with any procedure that supports CONTRAST statements.

Comment: I've never actually used the CONTRAST statement, so I cannot give advice on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another case where `PROC REG` with `TEST` works (`TEST x1=0, x2=0, x3=0, x4=0`, e.g.), which isn't answering my initial question for `PROC GLM`, but is an option if `PROC REG` gets the job done for your type of model.